# Denying access for HTTP methods in j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, configuration, jboss

I have a situation where I need to deny access to HTTP methods which are not used.
We are running on JBoss 4.2 and requires login. All other attempts to get access should be denied except GET and POST.

I have tried the following configurtation of web.xml, but it does not help. The servlet is still called and returns eg. a "Access denied" on a DELETE request.'
Instead I expect a `501: Not implemented` to be returned.
If I don't include any HTTP methods in the first security-constraint the user gets served an unauthorized page immediately.

```
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Deny most when not logged in</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!-- no auth-constraint tag here -->
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allow methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Any ideas on how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the different possibilities and Postman I found out that the first security-constraint is a blacklist. The http-methods added here are the ones that gets denied and JBoss returns a 403.
So the first security-constrain now looks like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Deny most when not logged in</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```